# Rank of a direct sum of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E=ℤ^{r}⊕T$ be a finitely generated abelian group. $T$ is a finite abelian group of rank $s$.

**My question** is about the rank of $E$. I thought that it is equal to $r+s$ but I am not sure about this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up the terms **rank** ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group)) and **order** ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29)). For any two abelian groups $A$ and $B$, it is true that
$$\mathrm{rank}(A\oplus B)=\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B),$$
but the rank of any finite abelian group is $0$, so the rank of $E$ in your question is still $r$.